@types/vscode After upgrading from 1.51.0 to 1.85.0, it reports that cannot find name 'thenable'
When implementing the getTreeItem method under vscode.TreeDataProvider, I used Thenable. After upgrading @types/vscode from 1.51.0 to 1.85.0, an error message
cannot find name 'thenable'will be reported. In addition, an error message will be reported that some codes in @types/node and @types/vscode files are missing ',' and ').
I tested that version 1.67.0 can run normally, but version 1.69.0started to report the above error

the project is in an intranet environment

When I do not use thenable, the error will disappear, but the mistake of missing ',' and ')' in the node and vscode files still exists. I hope to know the cause of this problem and the method to solve it.

Please provide additional details and more code to demonstrate how you utilize the given code.

... did you mean Thenable? TS type/interface names are case-sensitive.
